# javassist compilation error no such class

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, bigdecimal, javassist

I'm writing a program using javassist to compile another Java class. The generated class use some objects like `BigDecimal, List, ArrayList`. So I import their packages:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.insertClassPath(classDir); //classDir is my program Directory
pool.importPackage("java.util.List");
pool.importPackage("java.math.BigDecimal");
pool.importPackage("java.util.ArrayList");
```

Then I make some objects using `CtField.make()` for each object. When I use javassist to compile, it throws error:

```
CannotCompileException: [source error] no such class: BigDecimal
```

List is working fine, however, BigDecimal or ArrayList aren't. Is there any clue for this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing from `new BigDecimal()` by adding exact classPath as `new java.math.BigDecimal()` solves the problem!

Comment: Of course, then you can just delete all your import statements. Just like in regular Java code.

Answer (score 4):

As the name implies, `ClassPool.importPackage()` ([JavaDoc](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/ClassPool.html#importPackage-java.lang.String-)) is for importing packages, not classes. Considering that, you should use:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.insertClassPath(classDir); //classDir is my program Directory
pool.importPackage("java.util");
pool.importPackage("java.math");
```

*Note:* starting from Javassist 3.14, it does support importing also fully-qualified-class-names. So with that version, your original code should also work.